# Merge duplicate value in JSON array (underscore or lodash preferable)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js, lodash

I want to merge JSON arrays' some object which have duplicate values of specific key.

I have json Array Like this:

```
var data=[
    { type:"XO",
      logID:"213323",
      user:"34324234"
    },
    { type:"YO",
      logID:"2323323",
      user:"1212234"
    },
    { type:"XO",
      logID:"676323323",
      user:"45465412234"
    },
    ,
    { type:"ZO",
      logID:"1231434323",
      user:"35739434"
    }
]
```

Here I want to merge JSON Objects based on key 'type'. so same type will look like this with new key:

```
var expectedOutput:[
     { 
        type:XO,
        text: [
            {
              logID:"213323",
              user:"34324234"
            },
            {
              logID:"676323323",
              user:"45465412234"
            }
        ]
     },
     { type:"YO",
       text:[
         {
         logID:"2323323",
         user:"1212234"
        }  
      ]
     },
     {
       type:"ZO",
       text:[ 
           {
             logID:"1231434323",
             user:"35739434"
           } 
        ]
     }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`lodash#groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) to group the collection by `type`, use [`lodash#map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) to transform each group object format into a group array format. To remove the `type` property from the array of `text`, we'll use a partailly applied [`lodash#omit`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit) function using [`lodash#partial`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partial).

```
var result = _(data)
  .groupBy('type')
  .map(function(group, type) {
    return {
      type: type,
      text: _.map(group, _.partial(_.omit, _, 'type'))
    };
  })
  .value();
```

```js
var data = [{
    type: "XO",
    logID: "213323",
    user: "34324234"
  },
  {
    type: "YO",
    logID: "2323323",
    user: "1212234"
  },
  {
    type: "XO",
    logID: "676323323",
    user: "45465412234"
  },
  {
    type: "ZO",
    logID: "1231434323",
    user: "35739434"
  }
];

var result = _(data)
  .groupBy('type')
  .map(function(group, type) {
    return {
      type: type,
      text: _.map(group, _.partial(_.omit, _, 'type'))
    };
  })
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'ts because your input after the third item of the array is empty. I'll remove that from the input. You will notice that there are two commas "," after the third item in your `data` input.